Connect to mysql instance in GCP VM from Google Cloud Data Fusion
In GCP, I have created a VM instance and installed mysql instance in it. Now, I want to setup a connection to this mysql instance in Google Cloud Data Fusion.
I have downloaded and deployed the mysql jdbc drivers.
I tried to create a connection as below. I am using the internal IP address of the VM in host.

I am getting the error below when I test connection:

Failed to create connection to database via connection string:
jdbc:mysql://10.xx.xx.xx:3306 and arguments: {user=root,
rewriteBatchedStatements=true, connectTimeout=20000,
socketTimeout=20000}. Error: SocketTimeoutException: connect timed
out. Make sure you specify the correct connection properties.

